# Share laptop wifi connection to iPhone

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, internet, internet-sharing

I have windows sony vaio laptop which is connected to Internet through wifi. I want to share connection from laptop to iPhone. I see some articles on sharing Internet from laptop to device **WHEN** laptop is connected to **LAN**, but here my laptop is connected ti **WIFI**.

Please guide me on this. Links to articles will be fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, because the WiFi card cannot be connected to another WiFi spot as broadcasting his own signal. If you want to become a wireless hotspot, you'll loose connectivity with the internet. Therefor you'll need to be connected to internet with LAN. To do what you want, you'll need an external WiFi card.

Comment: I agree with Mathias. A secondary wifi dongle will be needed.